# Class Autoloading

Tags: 7

I seem to remember some autoloading functionality for classes in d7. Is there any documentation on this?

- How should one organise the files containing the classes?
- How can one make sure that parent-classes are loaded on instantiating a child-class?

I would like to avoid writing an autoloader for each module that has Classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drupal 7 maintains a [code registry](http://drupal.org/node/350780) and uses it for its classes autoloader. To populate this registry with your module's classes, you should add their files to the `files[]` entry in it's `.info` file:

```
files[] = includes/Foo.inc
files[] = includes/Bar.inc
```

PHP's class autoloading will make sure that the parent class file is also loaded.

Comment: .php extension is supported too? E.g: MyClass.class.php? What is Drupal convention here?

Comment: File extension does not matter, you can also put several classes in a single files.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, Pierre is correct.
Besides that, you can use [xautoload](http://drupal.org/project/xautoload) module to abbreviate your info file with wildcards.
Doc page: http://drupal.org/node/1976198

Syntax:

```
files[] = includes/*.inc
```

And besides that, you can attempt to be forward-compatible with Drupal 8, and use PSR-0 for your modules. This is also supported by xautoload.

Namespace and class: `\Drupal\my_module\OptionalSubNamespace\MyClass`
File: `(module dir)/lib/Drupal/my_module/OptionalSubNamespace/MyClass.php`

Doing this will make the files[] stuff obsolete.

Comment: If you use xautoload, then you can follow PSR-0 and starts using Drupal 8 class and namespace naming conventions and autoloader behavior.

Comment: that's what i'm saying, isn't it :)

Comment: is it possible to autoload a class found in a subfolder with xautoload?

e.g. in my hook_entity_info,
i added 
'controller class' => 'Drupal\myentity\controller\MyEntityController'

I have put my class in modules/myentity/lib/Drupal/controller/MyEntityController.php

but I get an error the controller class could not be loaded.

Comment: Hi yeahman, can you get on irc #drupal?

Comment: @yeahman Fact is, I used the scenario you mention a dozen of times. I imagine you simply have a bug in your code.. we can examine on irc.

Comment: what is your IRC channel? thx for helping

Comment: I have created a new question here instead: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108613/xautoload-classes-in-subfolders