# When can I, and when I can't rely on other module's classes to be loaded?

Tags: 7

I'm writing pluggable system. For a given *name*, I want to test if there is defined class pluginActionName. If it is, I want to create an instance of it. If it's not, I want to create an instance of pluginAction (parent class for all pluginAction* classes). That's the easy part, and Drupal unrelated.

Difficult about Drupal is to know when classes are defined. Can I rely on `class_exists`

- in my .inc code outside actual class? *no?*
- in initializers for static properties? *no?*
- in static methods of my class? *sometimes?*
- in dynamic methods of my class? *yes?*
- in helper functions that will be called by methods? *only if it would be OK in method?*

In *italics* is what I figured out so far, but I'm not sure about this and I cannot figure out exact loading order to tell **why** it's the way it is reliably.

Comment: The answer depends on your Drupal version. Can you update with which version you are using?

Comment: I left Drupal version out of it, because if there are differences between 6 and 7, I want to know them too. And a link to Drupal 8 methodology wouldn't hurt. I'm using 7 _right now_ but I want this as general and universal as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Drupal 7 introduces a code registry - an inventory of all classes and
>   interfaces for all enabled modules and Drupal's core files. The
>   registry stores the path to the file a given class or interface is
>   defined in, and loads the the file when necessary. The registry loads
>   classes and interfaces on demand, via php's built in class autoloading
>   mechanism. Modules can now move all code for classes that are not
>   regularly used into an include file, and Drupal will only load it on
>   demand. This will cut down on the amount of code loaded per request,
>   and reduce Drupal's memory footprint.

more info:

- http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21registry.inc/group/registry/7
- http://drupal.org/node/350780
- http://drupal.org/node/542202#files
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: So, in Drupal 7 I can safely load other module's classes at any point, and code registry will take care to make them available, right? No chance for a class reference used to soon?

Comment: If the class is added to the module.info file, e.g `files[] = myClass.class.php` it will be autoloaded, e.g `$object = new myClass($params);`

Comment: As long as the module author uses the new mechanism, you'll be OK.

Comment: Comments under that article suggests that even core maintainers (namely jhodgdon) aren't certain it's valid. And [Naming Convention](http://drupal.org/node/608152) indicates "Drupal does not mandate a class-file naming match." @AlfredArmstrong So how can I be sure to use that new mechanism?

Comment: Similar thread here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17621/in-drupal-7-how-does-drupal-handle-autoloading-of-classes

Comment: OK, so as long as all authors use file[], I can access classes at any time, stage of execution, right?

Comment: @Mołot the .info mechanism as highlighted by David above is reliable. This does not rely on a naming convention.

Comment: I'm not sure it works at /any/ stage. at hook_boot for example you generally have a very restricted set of APIs and other modules are not loaded so even if class loading works (not sure, as I say), other functions required by classes won't be available.