# Separate classes in include file not loading?

Tags: 7, .info

I have a peculiar problem... I'm trying to simplify my module by breaking up a ton of code into classes, and I have all of the classes in a separate include file that I'm registering in my .info file with the files[] directive.

However, when I go to use these classes in my module code, PHP dies.  It's like they're not being loaded.  I thought they were supposed to autoload at first use since I was using files[]?

**module.info**

```
name = Module
description = Module description
package = Module Package
core = 7.x

scripts[] = my_module.js
files[] = includes/my_module.class.inc
```

Comment: Just saying: You can simplify your life like this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/71939/2974

Answer (score 2):

The files listed in `files[]` do get autoloaded, but Drupal's registry needs to "find about" about them first. The .info files aren't parsed & processed on every page load, but rather only during specific system operations. Go to the `/admin/config/development/performance` page on your site and clear the cache - this will rebuild the registry and your files should then get loaded as necessary.

Comment: I had done this from the command line using `drush site.local cc all` numerous times, but changed nothing.  I just disabled, uninstalled, and re-installed the module and the classes finally loaded.  I'm totally confused on this one.

Comment: you MAY need to disable/re-enable (and potentially uninstall and then re-enable) your module for D7 to fully refresh everything IF you have added stuff to your .info file after initially enabling your module.