# xautoload classes in subfolders

Tags: 7

I have issues autoloading classes found in subfolders of my module with xautoload.

my module is called myentity

Here is my hook_entity_info

```
function myentity_entity_info() {
    $return['myentity'] = array(
        'label' => t('My entity'),
// The entity class and controller class extend the classes provided by the
// Entity API
        'entity class' => 'Drupal/myentity/class/MyEntity',
        'controller class' => 'Drupal/myentity/controller/MyEntityController',
        'base table' => 'myentity',
        'fieldable' => TRUE,
        'entity keys' => array(
            'id' => 'me_id',
            ),
        'bundles' => array(
        'myentity' => array(
            'label' => 'myentity',
        // Information below is used by the Field UI - they "attach" themselves here and lets us
        // do the standard field management that all the core entities enjoy.
            'admin' => array(
                'path' => 'admin/structure/myentity/manage',
                'access arguments' => array('administer myentity'),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    'label callback' => 'entity_class_label',
    'uri callback' => 'entity_class_uri',
    'module' => 'myentity',
    'view modes' => array(
        'full' => array(
            'label' => t('Default'),
            'custom settings' => FALSE,
        ),
        'teaser' => array(
            'label' => t('Teaser'),
            'custom settings' => FALSE,
        ),
    ),
    'metatags' => TRUE,
);

return $return;
}
```

My class and controller are found in

```
sites\all\modules\myentity\lib\Drupal\class\MyEntity.php
```

with the following content

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\myentity\class\MyEntity;

/**
 * The class used for model entities
 */
class MyEntity extends Entity {

    public function __construct($values = array()) {
        parent::__construct($values, 'myentity');
    }

    protected function defaultLabel() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    protected function defaultUri() {
        return array('path' => 'myentity/' . $this->identifier());
    }


}
```

and

```
sites\all\modules\myentity\lib\Drupal\controller\MyEntityController.php
```

Comment: I may be wrong as I don't know what xautoload does, but composer is PSR which means it autoloads based upon class name -> path. So if you call is `Drupal\myentity\class\MyEntity` it will autoload `sites\all\modules\Drupal\myentity\class\MyEntity.php` I believe you can tell it to look in a different folder, but the same sort of "structure" will apply.

Comment: Yes, it uses PSR-0 (and optionally PSR-4).

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/2229605 is this you?

Comment: This code features so many different mistakes that it would be a good candidate for a "troubleshooting" link for the xautoload module :)

Comment: hehe glad I was somehow "useful" haha

Comment: Btw this thing is quite close to your use case I think .. https://github.com/donquixote/drupal-nestedbox uses PSR-4 instead of PSR-0 but still..

Comment: Don't get confused by the module name being "nestedbox_core" instead of just "nestedbox". This is some paranoia on my side..

Comment: thx! will check this out. another question.. i want to extend my class from a class of another namespace

namespace Drupal\mymodule\classes;
class People extends \Drupal\mymodule\MyEntity {

}

I am getting an error that it cannot find \Drupal\mymodule\MyEntity

edit: never mind i think i got some naming wrong

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\myentity\subfolder\InsertQuery' not found in \includes\database\mysql\query.inc on line 14

i am getting that error whenever I call my class.. it's like other classes are trying to resolve to a namespace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bugs bugs bugs.

```
    'entity class' => 'Drupal/myentity/class/MyEntity',
    'controller class' => 'Drupal/myentity/controller/MyEntityController',
```

This should be

```
    'entity class' => 'Drupal\myentity\class\MyEntity',
    'controller class' => 'Drupal\myentity\controller\MyEntityController',
```

And:

```
namespace Drupal\myentity\class\MyEntity;
```

This should be

```
namespace Drupal\myentity\class;
```

(and btw, is "class" really a valid namespace part? Won't PHP complain?)

And:

```
sites\all\modules\myentity\lib\Drupal\controller\MyEntityController.php
```

This should be:

```
sites\all\modules\myentity\lib\Drupal\myentity\controller\MyEntityController.php
```

EDIT: One more:

```
class MyEntity extends Entity {
```

should be

```
class MyEntity extends \Entity {
```

Because class Entity is in root namespace.

Comment: I thought that PSR stuff was messed up, and yes `class` or `Class` will cause PHP to throw up.

Comment: So, does this work for you now?

Comment: thx for the reply.. i am always confused with the slashes lol (same for directory slashes.. I sometimes mess them up...)

seems to work except i get that error now:

Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\myentity\controller\EntityAPIController' not found in \sites\all\modules\al\myentity\lib\Drupal\myentity\controller\MyEntityController.php on line 8

my controller class is extending EntityAPIController:

   class MyEntityController extends EntityAPIController

Comment: Are you on Windows? https://drupal.org/node/2228501 I am going to commit this soon, but an additional feedback would be helpful.

Comment: Ah no sth else :) going to edit my post

Comment: Replace "extends EntityAPIController" with "extends \EntityAPIController".

Comment: seems to work fine! but why do i need to add this slash?

Comment: I am using https://drupal.org/node/2228501 version and it is working good on windows so far.

Comment: "why do I need to add this slash" - Because if your code is in a namespace, then every class name will be assumed to be relative to this namespace. So if you write "extends Entity" it will assume this means "extends \Drupal\myentity\..\Entity" instead of just "extends \Entity". The preceding backslash means this is an absolute namespace.

Comment: thx for the explanation! I never used namespace before.

Comment: I am glad that I can now organise my classes more cleanly.

Comment: instead of using "class" in my namespace, can i use "classes"?

Comment: yes. but i don't see the point why you would introduce this step in the hierarchy.

Comment: but honestly, this (whether "classes" works) would have been easy to figure out for yourself, wouldn't it?

Comment: lol yup classes is working fine